# Issue when creating custom styled Mui v5 component with custom props

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to created a styled component using the styled funcion from mui

```js
// Imports 
import styled from '@mui/system/styled';
import Select, { SelectChangeEvent, SelectProps } from '@mui/material/Select';

// Extended props
interface SelectComponentAddedProps extends SelectProps {
  bool: boolean;
}

// Mui Styled Component
// Style for the select component
export const StyledSelect = styled(Select)<SelectComponentAddedProps>(({ theme, bool }) => ({
  width: bool ? 'fit-content' : 300,
  textAlign: 'start',
  margin: '5px',
  fontWeight: 800,
}));
 
// Component in render 
<StyledSelect
variant={variant}
labelId='select-label'
name={name}
disabled={disabled}
value={value}
renderValue={(value: unknown) => {
if (typeof value === 'string') {
return renderValue(name, value, options.length);
}
}}
onChange={onChangeFn}
displayEmpty
disableUnderline
>
```

and I am getting the follwoing error massage

> Blockquote react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: React does not recognize the `disableUnderline` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `disableunderline` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.

How to be able to create a styled component with my custom props that will be compatible with the basic props of the component ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your styled component is dependent on a prop from your base component to generate its styles, then you need to pass that prop to your styled component as well. However, you don't want to propagate it further into the Select component.

```js
// Use the "bool" prop in your styles, but don't forward it to the Select component
export const StyledSelect = styled(Select, {
  shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== 'bool', // <----
})<SelectComponentAddedProps>(({ bool }) => ({
  width: bool ? 'fit-content' : 300,
  textAlign: 'start',
  margin: '5px',
  fontWeight: 800,
}));

// In your base component:
<StyledSelect
  // ...
  bool={/*...*/} // Pass the "bool" prop to the Styled Component
/>
```

Comment: so it is like do this and stop ... thus it will prevent the error

Comment: Yeah, basically. You need the prop in the styled component because of the conditional styles (width in your example). But the "bool" prop is not a prop of the Select component in itself, so it shouldn't be forwarded to it